# Call of a suspicious method cannot be found

Tags: android

i have a strange apk which I took a closer look at, among others with jadx-gui. It is a gaming app that requires an unusual amount of permissions according to the manifest file. I installed and played the game on a testphone. The requested permissions are not allowed for the game at all. Found a class in the code with the following suspicious method:

```
public void doInBackground()
{
  ...
  String deviceId = ((TelephonyManager) this.a.getSystemService("phone")).getDeviceId();
  ...
  a.add(new BasicNameValuePair(new String("imei"), deviceId)); 
  ...
  try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(a));
      } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
  ...
```

This method collects sensitive data and sends it via http.
I don't see that this class is called with this method. Searched for the name of the method, but found nothing. Is there a way to call this method without seeing it in the jadx-gui?
Otherwise I ask myself why this method was implemented if it is never used.

Answer (score 1):

In Android there is a class named `AsyncTask`, designed for running processes in the background without blocking the UI.

The developer extends `AsyncTask` and implements `doInBackground()` member function which is called by the system. After instancing the derived class and calling the instance's `.execute()` method, Android will, asynchronously call `doInBackground()`.

The program does not call functions of `AsyncTask` directly.

Link to documentation:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask